Locating coordinates of Text, scrolling to, and zooming in on them in a windows form project
I'm trying to implement a program that allows the user to enter a value, search the PDF, then scroll to and zoom in if the text is found. I want all this to happen inside my application, without opening a pdf software separately.  I'm having trouble achieving that. The closest I've gotten so far is displaying the pdf in a panel, I can find the text, and I can zoom in. But I seem to be struggling to find the correct coordinates and scroll to them. I'm currently using PdfiumViewer and Itext7. I'm open to using whatever library is capable of doing this.

private RectangleF FindTextPosition(string pdfPath, string searchText)
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath))
    using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(reader))
    {
        var strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();

        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
        {
            var page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);

            PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
            var locations = strategy.GetResultantLocations();

            foreach (var location in locations)
            {
                if (location.Text.IndexOf(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    foundText = true;
                    return new RectangleF(location.Rectangle.Left, location.Rectangle.Right, location.Rectangle.Width, location.Rectangle.Height );
                    
                }

            }
        }

    }


    return RectangleF.Empty;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //search button
{
    string searchText = textBox1.Text;
    RectangleF position = FindTextPosition(pdfPath, searchText);
    
    if (foundText == true) 
    {
        PdfRectangle pdfRect = ConvertToPdfRectangle(position);


        viewer.Zoom = 4.0f;
        viewer.ScrollIntoView(pdfRect);

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(position.ToString());
  
    }
    else
    {
        

    }
}




"But I seem to be struggling to find the correct coordinates and scroll to them." - What does that mean exactly? What of which you are doing is attempting to perform this, what did you expect and what happens instead?

^^ Also: what happens if you do not zoom? Is the position correct, then? If so, you probably also need to apply that "zoom" on your scrolling. - OR try scroll first, then zoom.

Unrelated: Do not depend on sideeffects of methods like setting that foundText flag. For this case, I would consider a variation of the bool TryX( out var result ) pattern: bool TryFindTextPosition ( string pdfPath, string searchText, out RectangleF position )

@KJ "loose the comment about multiple software that is a reason for closure on grounds of asking." - I read that as "I am not married to the libs I mentioned and will accept answers that need me to replace them." OP is not really asking to suggest a lib. Close, but not exactly.

@KJ One, not sure what you mean by your first comment. I'm simply looking for a library that can render a PDF and take me to specific coordinates. Second, PDFium is the viewer, where I render the PDF inside a panel in the project. Itext is used to find the coordinates of the text.

@Fildor Without zooming, nothing happens. The PDF is one page, and it all fits in the panel itself, so there's nothing to really move to. I've messed around with adding like rectangles or labels where the coordinates result is and it seems to be off. I'm thinking its taking the actual PDF, gathering its coordinates then returning that. But the PDF is in a panel so the size is smaller. Thats the best I got. I'm very new to coding so sorry that I dont know more..

Well, if you are able to find a pattern in the "it is off", then you may be able to fix it. If you have different pdfs and different positions but the same zoom level, let's say - is it a fix amount of pixels that it is off? Is it off more or less depending on the actual position (like further "down" = more error in y-Direction e.g.) ? That might give you a hint whether you need to account for maybe some padding, margin, factor the zoom into translation ...

^^ Important: If you have the same pdf and scroll to the same position, is it off by always the same amount?
